# Limiting the number of sessions per machine in OBIEE 12c more than once

Tags: oracle, weblogic, business-intelligence, obiee

I want to prevent users to login in Oracle BI12c with the same "username" more than once.
also, I checked many documents and see parameter like "Max Session Limit" but its not worked for my problem.

thank for your guidance to have any solution

Answer (score 1):

You can configure this using Database Resource Manager, or by creating a customized profile for the group of users you want to limit sessions for.

Oracle's documentation on profiles can be found at the following link. You want to define the `SESSIONS_PER_USER` parameter as 1.  https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_6012.htm#SQLRF01310

**Edit based on the additional Requirements:**

After giving it some thought, I'm not sure if you could do something like this at the profile level, You'll probably have to do something like creating a trigger based on the `v$session` table. `v$session` has `SCHEMANAME`, `OSUSER`, and `MACHINE`. Since your users are sharing the same schema, you may be able to create a trigger that throws an error like "ERROR: Only one Connection per User/Machine" based on either the `MACHINE` or the `OSUSER` columns in the `v$session` table. This is less than ideal for a number of reasons, and your developers will probably hate you, but if you absolutely need to do something like this, it is possible.

Comment: My intention is doing this configuration in OBIEE 12c suit or Weblogic application server because my system users don't exist in the database. OBIEE just have two default schemas as "DEV_BIPLATFORM" and "DEV_MDS" on its own database and I think cannot restrict any sessions with this solution on the database .

Comment: I'd recommend changing your question to reflect that technical requirement. You've received an answer on how to limit the number of sessions per username, but that is not what you want. Since your users are using the same username/schema, you probably want a method for limiting the number of sessions per machine, which will be a little more involved.

Comment: Thanks, I change my question. do you have any solution about it.

Comment: After giving it some thought, I'm not sure if you could do something like this at the profile level, You'll probably have to do something like create a trigger based on the `v$session` table. `v$session` has `SCHEMANAME`, `OSUSER`, and `MACHINE`. Since your users are sharing the same schema, you may be able to create a trigger that throws an error like "ERROR: Only one Connection per User/Machine" based on those columns in `v$session`. This is less than ideal for a number of reasons, and your developers will probably hate you, but if you absolutely need to do something like this it is possible

Answer (score 1):

Just as a wrap-up. OBIEE is an analytical platform and you have to think about connections in a different way. As cdb_dba said:
1.) take a step back
2.) think about what you want to do
3.) learn and comprehend how the tool works and does things
4.) decide on how you implement and control things by matching #2 and #3

Comment: do you think that's my problem is basically was wrong and I can not handle connections for using OBIEE tool

Comment: No. The problem is that you need to be clear on what you want to do. The REQUIREMENT that needs to be fulfilled. Not what you think should be the technical solution. WHAT do you want to do is important, not HOW you think it should be done.

Comment: I use OBIEE for analytical work. now my company wants to grant "Security Confirmation" to this app. one of the items in this checklist is "The tool doesn't allow Users to login and work with an application with more than once per machine or even browser".Now my question: Does OBIEE 12c can handle these type of request?

Comment: "The tool doesn't allow Users to login and work with an application with more than once per machine or even browser".  That question doesn't even make sense to begin with since I can work with 20 browser tabs in Firefox plus 20 in Chrome at the same time without any issue. Again - the issue is that it seems the question doesn't make sense as it is unclear HOW they can even think that.

Comment: okay, I know it. the answer to this question is the tools can't support.

Comment: No. WRONG. The problem is that there is a misunderstanding in HOW the tool actually works. This isn't an OLTP app where you limit things to one single connection to ensure consistency. Analytics works differently. Claiming that "the tool can't support it" is wrong.

Comment: The problem is that they compare it with OLTP app.

Comment: Very intelligent. Ask them whether they also compare a pair of inline skates to a Formula 1 car just because both are means to get you from A to B.

Comment: +1 on everything that Chris said. You will often get technical requirements from the business side that maybe won't make sense. If they've developed an application where multiple people are relying on the same username/schema, and they want to be able to control individual connections at the username level, you probably want to revisit how those connections are happening. Sure, theres probably a less-than-ideal way to implement it based on the odd requirements given to you, but you (and the people who come after you) will save a lot of time/effort by clearly defining the scope of whats needed